# How to have a program that uses the pointer ptr for reading and printing stuff about a book struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

How to have a program that uses the pointer ptr for reading and printing stuff about a book struct without using any other variable. For the access to the stuff of the struct i have to use the `->`
My program terminates after the first read.
Can somebody provide me with a code?
 Here is my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct book {
    char title[100];
    char authors;
    int code;
    double prc;
};

int main(void) {
    struct book *ptr;
    printf("Title:\n");
    gets(&ptr->title[100]);
    printf("authors:\n");
    gets(&ptr->authors);
    printf("code:\n");
    scanf("%d",&ptr->code);
    printf("Price:\n");
    scanf("%lf",&ptr->prc);

    printf("T:%s,A:%s,C:%d,P:lf\n",ptr->title,ptr->authors,ptr->code,ptr->prc);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the program to read these 4 things about a book and then prints them in the final printf using only the pointer `ptr`

Comment: Allocate you book or do not use a pointer placing it in the stack. do not use _gets_, use _fgets_ to limit the size, verify your _scanf_ return 1 to check the user enter a valid input.

Comment: Never use [gets](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html), its usage is depreciated. Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: Also this `&ptr->title[100]` is wrong. Since `title` is character buffer, its name itself address, use `scanf("%s", ptr->title);` or `fgets(ptr->title, sizeof(ptr->title), stdin);` and check the return value of `fgets()` or `scanf()` whichever you are going to use..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems

- you missed to allocate your instance of *book*
- `&ptr->title[100]` is invalid
- the use of *gets* is deprecated since years, use *fgets* to limit the size and avoid undefined behavior
- you missed to check your *scanf* return 1 to know if a valid input was done
- you have a memory leak because of the *malloc* without a *free*, and in fact you do not need to allocate your book in the heap
- are you sure just a char is enough for *authors* ? probably you wanted an array
- `gets(&ptr->authors);` is invalid because *authors* is just a character
- the format "%s" for *authors* is invalid because it is just a character
- you missed a % before "lf" to print the price

Probably you do not want the newline in the input string

You wanted something like :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct book {
    char title[100];
    char authors[100];
    int code;
    double prc;
};

int main(void) {
    struct book * ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct book));
    size_t len;

    printf("Title:\n");
    if (fgets(ptr->title, sizeof(ptr->title), stdin) == NULL)
      /* EOF */
      return -1; /* or an other behavior is you want */
    len = strlen(ptr->title);
    if (ptr->title[len - 1] == '\n')
      ptr->title[len - 1] = 0;
    printf("authors:\n");
    if (fgets(ptr->authors, sizeof(ptr->authors), stdin) == NULL)
      /* EOF */
      return -1;/* or an other behavior is you want */
    len = strlen(ptr->authors);
    if (ptr->authors[len - 1] == '\n')
      ptr->authors[len - 1] = 0;
    printf("code:\n");
    if (scanf("%d",&ptr->code) != 1) {
      puts("invalid code");
      return 1; /* or an other behavior is you want */
    }
    printf("Price:\n");
    if (scanf("%lf",&ptr->prc) != 1) {
      puts("invalid price");
      return 1; /* or an other behavior is you want */
    }

    printf("T:%s,A:%s,C:%d,P:%lf\n",ptr->title,ptr->authors,ptr->code,ptr->prc);

    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

or without allocating the book in the heap :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct book {
    char title[100];
    char authors[100];
    int code;
    double prc;
};

int main(void) {
    struct book b;
    size_t len;

    printf("Title:\n");
    if (fgets(b.title, sizeof(b.title), stdin) == NULL)
      /* EOF */
      return -1; /* or an other behavior is you want */
    len = strlen(b.title);
    if (b.title[len - 1] == '\n')
      b.title[len - 1] = 0;
    printf("authors:\n");
    if (fgets(b.authors, sizeof(b.authors), stdin) == NULL)
      /* EOF */
      return -1;/* or an other behavior is you want */
    len = strlen(b.authors);
    if (b.authors[len - 1] == '\n')
      b.authors[len - 1] = 0;
    printf("code:\n");
    if (scanf("%d",&b.code) != 1) {
      puts("invalid code");
      return 1; /* or an other behavior is you want */
    }
    printf("Price:\n");
    if (scanf("%lf",&b.prc) != 1) {
      puts("invalid price");
      return 1; /* or an other behavior is you want */
    }

    printf("T:%s,A:%s,C:%d,P:%lf\n",b.title,b.authors,b.code,b.prc);

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Title:
the mirific title
authors:
me
code:
007
Price:
12.34
T:the mirific title,A:me,C:7,P:12.340000
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: `gets` is not only deprecated. It was removed 2011.

Comment: @Broman unfortunately it is not "completely" removed, with gcc version 6.3 it is still possible to use it, there is a warning but the link find it :-(

Comment: I get a lot of compiling errors using the first solution

Comment: and yeah gets can still be used using devc++

Comment: @bruno That's true. But it's no longer a part of the standard.

Comment: @Johny21111 oh yes, I did by head, I correct and I warn you when it is done ;-)

Comment: in line 25 i get "missing terminating character"
in line 7 i get "missing terminating character"
in line 12 i get "invalid conversion from 'void*' to'book*'"
in line 21 i get"expected primary expression before return"
and in line 26 i get"expected primary expression before return"

Comment: @Johny21111 corrected, I missed to close 2 literal string smore other details, update/read again

Comment: @bruno i get a final error in line 12 "invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'book' "

Comment: @Johny21111 what is line 12 for you ? the malloc ? are you sure you compile in C rather than in C++ ?

Comment: struct book *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct book));

Comment: fixed it. my bad

Comment: @Johny21111 wait a little there are other problems

Comment: University stuff... can t concentrate to one programming language, we have to fight with all of them and not getting good and used to one...

Comment: yeah there are some problems when printing

Comment: @Johny21111 ok, get the new version, I removed the newline and added the missing % for the price

Comment: @Johny21111 you welcome, sorry for he errors, happy coding / studies

Answer (score 1):

You have to allocate memory first.

```
struct book *ptr = malloc(sizeof (*ptr));
```

Also, never use the function `gets`. It have been removed. [Read here why it is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/6699433)

Besides, the call to `gets` is wrong. The argument should be `ptr->title`. But use this instead:

```
fgets(ptr->title, 100, stdin);
```

And always check the return value from `scanf` to ensure everything went ok.

Comment: @Achal Not really necessary for small programs, and I think the answer becomes to broad if I would address all the flaws.